# Change state of something from another class with a button

Tags: reactjs, button, react-hooks, use-state, react-hook-form

I am new to React and have had some hard time to understand the concept of states.

Down below I export a stepper from MUI. I use state

```
export default function CustomizedSteppers() {
  const steps = ['Zoninfo', 'Betalsätt', 'Börja ladda'];
 const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const handleNext = () => {
      setActiveStep((activeStep+1));
    };

 

 return (
  //...
  //Stepper stuff...
  //...

  <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleNext}>Hello 
  World</Button>

  
</Stack>

 );
}
```

I now want to split this code so that I can setActiveStep from another component.

Meaning, I want to put the button outside of this component and put it in another class, but still allow that button to change the value of activeStep - by accessing the method handleNext on click on a button outside this class. How do I manage to do this?

Comment: you can achieve this with state management tools like contextApi or Redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a parent component, define `activeStep` and `handleNext` there, and pass them to your `CustomizedSteppers`

Parent.js

```
import CustomizedSteppers from "./CustomizedSteppers"
export default function Parent() {
  const steps = ['Zoninfo', 'Betalsätt', 'Börja ladda'];
 const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const handleNext = () => {
      setActiveStep((activeStep+1));
    };

return (
    <>
      <CustomizedSteppers activeStep={activeStep} handleNext={handleNext}>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleNext}>Hello 
      World</Button>
    </>
  )
}
```

CustomizedSteppers.js

```
export default function CustomizedSteppers({activeStep, handleNext}) {
    return (
    //...
    //Stepper stuff...
    //...

  


    </Stack>

 );
}
```

Comment: the problem will be that button would appear twice on the page. I want the button to be outside of everything but still be able to change the activestep in customizedsteppers.

Comment: You can remove the button in `CustomizedSteppers`. I forgot to remove it. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! one question, is it possible to keep the button in a separate class so that it is not with customized steppers? I want to put the button in form1 - while the stepper will be independent and presentable on all pages. All form should contain buttons that can control the activestep - this by not being in the same class as the stepper.

Comment: Yes, you can make a Button component and pass handleNext as prop.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.

The first is to [lift your state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), like @Peter said. That is, you'll need to move activeStep to the component that houses both this component and the other component you want to have activeStep's value, and then pass that value to both (a practice known as prop drilling). This is probably the simplest way, if this is the only variable you want to do that for.

The second is to use state management tools, like @ahmetkilinc said. [The Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is native to React, so it won't require any extra installations or tools. There are also third-party tools like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) that try to solve this problem (though I believe Redux is still just using Contexts behind the scenes, anyway). This option is better if this is a need you anticipate having multiple times throughout your application.

Comment: Another nice third-party tool is Zustand, https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the state updating function as a prop to your component.
Your Button Component:

```html
function CustomButtonComponent (props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => props.setCount(count => count + 1)}>
        Click me
    </button>
  )
}

export default CustomButtonComponent
```

And In Your Main Component

```
<CustomButtonComponent setCount={setCount} />
```

Also Since state updates are scheduled in React, you shouldnt use

```
onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
```

Instead use

```
onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}
```

Comment: Yes that works fine indeed. However I realized that I had to clarify more details about the issue since it does not work in my situation. I've changed the content of the question now

Answer (score 1):

Try understanding following code .

```
const Child = (props)=>{

   return (
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={props.handleNext}>Hello 
        World</Button>
   )
}

const Parent = ()=>{
 const steps = ['Zoninfo', 'Betalsätt', 'Börja ladda'];
 const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
 const handleNext = () => {
     setActiveStep((activeStep+1));
 };

 return (
  
  <Child handleNext={(e)=>handleNext(e)} />
 )
}
```

Take this code as a sample example and try implementing it with your code .

**What is happening in this Parent Function ?**

We are passing **handleNext** as a **prop** to to **Child component** which triggers handleNext function inside Parent component when a **button** is **clicked** inside **Child component**.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to move that Child component to another class and keep the same functionality?